# Tkinter Python gui login isn't working, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

My GUI Login is skipping over the If part of my If Statement, I don't understand what would be wrong, how can I go about fixing this bug? It should be using the If part when the Username and Password are correct but for some reason it doesn't seem to think that it is part of it.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("My Login")
root.geometry("650x650")

frame = Frame(root)

app = Frame(root)
app.grid

l = Label(root, text = "Login",font="Times 30", padx=5,  pady=5)
l.grid()

l1 = Label(root, text = "Username:",font="Times 30", padx=5,  pady=5)
l1.grid()

l2 = Label(root, text = "Password:",font="Times 30", padx=5,  pady=5)
l2.grid()

user = Entry(root)
user.grid( row= 1, column= 2)
user.configure(font = ("Courier", 44))
code = Entry(root)
code.grid( row= 2, column= 2)
code.configure(font = ("Courier", 44))

operator = user.get()
passcode = code.get()

admin = ""  #This would be the Username
password = ""  #This would be the Password

def enter():
    if (operator == admin and passcode == password):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.Popen("") #This would be a directory to open
    else: 
        l3 = Label(root, text = "check login", font=("Courier", 22))
        l3.grid()

b1 = Button(root, text = "Enter", command = enter, font=("Courier", 44))
b1.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't preassign the values from get(), you have to call those at the moment you need them.

```
def enter():
    if user.get() == admin and code.get() == password:
        import subprocess # this belongs at the top of the file
        subprocess.Popen("")
    else: 
        l3 = Label(root, text = "check login", font=("Courier", 22))
        l3.grid()
```